# What's the best way of getting an instagram feed in PHP?

Tags: php, instagram

Need to show instagram photos, comments count, like count etc in a customized design. Any suggested way of doing this? Widgets available do not help.

Answer (score 0):

http://instagram.com/developer/

is the URL where you can get the details of the Instagram API and its authentication.

You will have to do everything from authentication till fetching a feed.

Comment: Thanks Arfeen,

Looked as if was too much to do for a simple task, I ended up using the RSS and parsing in PHP, which did the trick.